# Rails how to use time stamp in select clause in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I need to do a query like so:

```
Advert.select("COUNT(*), (
  CASE WHEN created_at > '#{1.hour.ago}' THEN '1 hour ago'
  WHEN created_at > '#{2.hours.ago}' THEN '2 hours ago' 
  WHEN created_at > '#{3.hours.ago}' THEN 'more than 3 hours' END
) as time_frame").group("time_frame")
```

The problem is, that the time stamp rails puts into the query is wrong due to time zone setup with database. Normally in a `where`-clause I would do it with placeholders e.g. like so: `where("created_at > ?", 1.hour.ago)` however this feature does not seem to exist for `select`-clauses. How do I then do the select with correct database query?

**edit**

Here is the difference between what the two methods renders SQL-wise:

WRONG: `SELECT count(*), (CASE WHEN created_at > '2015-08-14 12:00:20 +0200' THEN`...

and

RIGHT: ...`FROM "adverts"  WHERE (created_at > '2015-08-14 10:00:20.944724')`...

Comment: how do you save in your database? thats the questions key

Comment: I don't do anything specifically. Rails does it all for me :-)

Comment: oh i see. you dont have a timezone problem, your probilem is a strange querystring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query is working fine for me, can't reproduce your problem

```
2.2.1 :088 >   Time.now
 => 2015-08-14 13:28:31 +0200 

2.2.1 :089 > Time.now.zone
 => "CEST" 

2.2.1 :090 > User.select(a).group("time_frame")
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*), (
  CASE WHEN created_at > '2015-08-14 10:25:06 UTC' THEN '1 hour ago'
  WHEN created_at > '2015-08-14 09:25:06 UTC' THEN '2 hours ago' 
  WHEN created_at > '2015-08-14 08:25:06 UTC' THEN 'more than 3 hours' 
  END
  ) as time_frame FROM `users` GROUP BY time_frame

 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: nil>]>
```

but right now i wonder wherer your `last_observed_at` is coming from

Comment: Sorry, last_observed_at was a typo

Comment: can you please go into the console and save the string into a varaible and do the same like i did and post the output here? i seriously wonder that this isnt working with you

Comment: [1] pry(main)> Time.now
=> 2015-08-14 13:46:12 +0200
[2] pry(main)> Time.now.zone
=> "CEST"

Comment: In your version it seems to be changing timestamps to UTC. How does your `a`-variable look?